# Can't import android.os.StrictMode?

Tags: android, android-strictmode

In my program, I can't  import `android.os.StrictMode` even I change SDK version.What pronblem is it? In `android.os`, `StrictMode` can't be found.
 I don't know what to do.

```
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Comment: you need sdk>9 i guez

Comment: No, I didn't work.. however, thz your advice.

Comment: It's not your Manifest, it's the sdk version you are compiling against, do you know which you are using?

Comment: I don't know exactly. Which way I find it?

Comment: StrictMode should only be used during development and not in your live application.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the build target from project properties

Answer (score 0):

Just verify once by doing this:
- Go to Project properties by right clicking on the project.
- Select Android from left pane and check API level > 9. I feel you select the maximum level because, it's just required for compilation. Anyway, you can set your min SDK version in Manifest file.
- Sometimes, it doesn't load Android APIs even though you have set it properly, so you have to do above mentioned step. Then, clean & build.